# calculation of partition function: choice of a cross-section

Tags: differential-topology, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

Given a TFT $Z$, I aim to calculate the partition function $Z(\mathbb{S}^2)$ as discussed by Lurie on page-7, Example 1.2.1 in:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0465

If I am not wrong I do need to show that the value $Z(\mathbb{S}^2)$ is independent of the choice of the cross-section used to decompose $\mathbb{S}^2$ into a 'cup' and a 'cap'. In this case it is easy to see that this is inddeed the case. However, let me approach this problem differently. If we choose a different cross-section $S_2$ ($S_1$ being the first), and if $S_1S_2$ forms the boundary of a cylinder $C = (-S_1) \sqcup S_2$, then the result follows from the fact that fact that $Z$ is a symmetric-monoidal functor to the category of $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces, using the composite $$ \emptyset \to S_1 \to S_2 \to \emptyset $$ My question is: what will happen if $S_1$ and $S_2$ do not form a cylinder and instead intersects (for instance when both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are great circles)? Definitely, I am viewing $\mathbb{S}^2$ as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and I think even when $S_1$ and $S_2$ intersects in embedded picture, there exists a representative in the diffeomorphism class of $\mathbb{S}^2$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ does form a cylinder and the result follows. Am I right?
My actual problem is much more serious in nature but while working on that this problem caught my attention.
Maybe I am asking a stupid/obvious question.

Comment: What you are proposing is not s legitimate decomposition of the sphere. The most charitable reading of your proposal is that you would take two hemispheres bounded by two crossing great circles in $S^2$. But the union of such hemispheres is not $S^2$ and their intersection is not a 1-dimensional submanifold.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't know if you understood the question, but your response did give me the answer. Correct me if I am wrong. To calculate, partition function, we need a height function $f$  whose co-domain serves as the time coordinate. Then a cross-section will be of the form $f^{-1}(t)$ and thus what I am asking is ill-defined.

Comment: You fo not absolutely need a Morse function (which is a better name than "height") but using one is a good way to partition a manifold.